# Convert nested list to data frame while preserving column types

Tags: r, list, nested

Given a list, `b01`, of lists: `tp01`, `tp02`, `tp03`, where each `tp` stores a specific type of data, how do I extract the class of each `tp`?

The goal is to return a single data frame that preserves the original variable's type (e.g. int, char). I was thinking of extracting the classes of each `tp` and storing them, then overwriting the data frame's classes with those stored classes.

In the example below, the resulting data frame has 3 variables that are considered `Factor`. I would like them to be considered `int`, `char`, `int`.

I tried the following without luck:

```
str(as.data.frame(lapply(b01,unlist)))
str(sapply(as.data.frame(lapply(b01,unlist)),class))
lapply(b01,unlist)
sapply(str(lapply(b01,unlist)),unlist)
```

MWE:

```
set.seed(1)
tp01 <- list(sample(seq(0,100),10))
set.seed(2)
tp02 <- list(sample(seq(0,100),10))
tp03 <- list(letters[c(sample(seq(0,26),10))])
b01 <- list(tp01, tp02, tp03)

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(lapply(all,unlist)),
    nrow=length(unlist(b01[1]))*length(all)))
> df
   V1 V2 V3
1  26  q 18
2  37  j 70
3  56  t 56
4  89  c 16
5  19  g 91
6  86  y 90
7  97  w 12
8  62  v 78
9  58  r 43
10  5  b 50
11 18 26  q
12 70 37  j
13 56 56  t
14 16 89  c
15 91 19  g
16 90 86  y
17 12 97  w
18 78 62  v
19 43 58  r
20 50  5  b

str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 19 levels "12","16","18",..: 5 6 10 16 4 15 19 12 11 8 ...
 $ V2: Factor w/ 20 levels "19","26","37",..: 15 14 17 12 13 20 19 18 16 11 ...
 $ V3: Factor w/ 20 levels "12","16","18",..: 3 7 6 2 10 9 1 8 4 5 ...
```

Comment: @RichScriven also just `data.frame(unlist(b01,recursive=FALSE))`.

Comment: @nicola - yeah that's the one ;)

Comment: Also need to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to get character instead of factor.

Comment: And if you name the elements of your original list, then those will be returned as the column names of the data frame (e.g., `b01 <- list(tp01=tp01, tp02=tp02, tp03=tp03)`, or `b01 <- Hmisc::llist(tp01, tp02, tp03)`).

Comment: Thanks all. Is there a way to preserve the variable names as `tp01`, `tp02` , `tp03`?

Comment: Yes. See my previous comment.

Comment: @eipi10 Any way to do it without having to manually type each `tp__`? The actual use-case involves many thousands of `tp__`.

Comment: For your example (using `str_pad` from the `stringr` package) `b01 = mget(paste0("tp", str_pad(1:3,width=2,pad=0)))`. In your actual use case, if you have no more than 9999 "tp" and assuming the values less than 1000 have leading zeros,  `b01 = mget(paste0("tp", str_pad(1:num.tp, width=4, pad=0)))`. You can, of course, adjust accordingly for your actual "tp" values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with lapply and as.data.frame:

```
names(b01) <- c("tp01","tp02","tp03")  #optional
first.step <- lapply(b01, unlist) 
second.step <- as.data.frame(first.step, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

See unlist() documentation for info on coercion with that step. The stringsAsFactors = F argument will preserve the character vector in the second step.